# Unable to reproduce example from python tutorial: match function gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error, match

I'm trying to reproduce an example that I've found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).
I guess the match function is not recognised:

```
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"

  File "<ipython-input-151-1f275f95d012>", line 2
    match status:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought maybe the match function is missing, so I did `import re` and then replaced the `match` with `re.match`, but that also didn't work.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: are you running python 3.10?

Comment: `match` is a new feature in Python, only available in the latest 3.10 version.